# Control level ValidateRequestMode has no effect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, request-validation

I'm using ASP.NET WebForms (.NET 4.5) and have an "content block" control, which is reused on a number of pages. I've tried setting the ValidateRequestMode of the control and even individual elements to "Disabled", but the request validation coming from web.config still prevents unsafe input.

Is there a way around this or am I doing something wrong?

Example:

Answer (score 10):

I just solved this same problem for a site with the code below, after a morning of trial and error - Microsoft's documentation on the new Request Validation process seems to be wrong when it comes to WebForms.

Target .NET 4.5 in the web.config like this:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5" />
```

And then adding `ValidateRequestMode="Disabled"`to the input controls themselves i.e.:

```
<asp:textbox id="myControl" runat="server" ValidateRequestMode="Disabled"/>
```

If you are accessing POST data directly (as opposed to via myControl.Text) You will also need to bypass validation at that point:

```
Request.Unvalidated.Form("myControl");
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jason Elkin.

As a supplement, after setting `ValidateRequestMode="Disabled"`
on *Control* level, in server-end, whenever accessing to *Request* , you have to visit *Request.Unvalidated* to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

This answer extends @Jason Elkin's answer above to .NET Framework 4.8 and limiting the scope of its relaxed security to a specific directory.  As previously reported,
`ValidateRequestMode="Disabled"` by itself did not work for me.  What *did* work was inserting the following into my ASP.NET application project Web.config file:

```
  <location path="pages/ajax">
    <system.web>
      <!-- enable AJAX -->
      <xhtmlConformance mode="Strict" />
      <!-- this allows HTML content to post back when control's ValidateRequestMode="Disabled" -->
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" requestValidationMode="4.8" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

where `"pages/ajax"` is the relative path from the web.config directory to the directory that contains the web forms that post HTML input.